# How to make a Scatter plot with D3 using a JSON file as input

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My goal is to make a scatter plot using D3, and I cannot figure how to work with the data to successfully create the plot using svg. The data is in JSON format:

```
data = {
    time_to_read: {0: 1.31, 1: 2.565, 2: 4.6, 3: 3.05, 4: 2.605} 
    sentiment: {0: -0.003816794, 1: 0.0331384, 2: 0.011956521, 3: -0.021311475,4: 0.038387716}
    scrollreach_label: {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1}
       }
```

After building the axes, I have tried something like this to add the points:

```
  Svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
     .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d3.values(d['avg_scroll_reach']) )} )
     .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d3.values(d['visits'])) } )
     .attr("r", 5)
```

but this doesn't work, nothing is plotted on the graph.

The plot I need to create should look roughly like this (using much more data in this case):
[image]

Comment: you use (d3.values(d.avg_scroll_reach)) but the key `avg_scroll_reach` isnt in your json right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, basically by formatting the data differently to start with. Originally the data was in pandas format, since I am using a Python back end. So instead of converting the Pandas data to JSON using

```
data_json = data.to_json()
```

I used

```
data_json = data.to_json(orient='records')
```

This outputs the data in the format I needed:

```
 Array(32) [
  0: Object {time_to_read: , sentiment: 0.1, scrollreach_label: 3}
  1: Object {time_to_read: , sentiment: 0.1, scrollreach_label: 2}
  2: Object {time_to_read: "Datsun 710", sentiment: 0.2, scrollreach_label: 1}
  3: Object {time_to_read: "Hornet 4 Drive", sentiment: 0.1, scrollreach_label: 3}
...
]
```

Then, I use the following code to plot:

```
  Svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
   .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", d => x(d.avg_scroll_reach))
    .attr("cy", d => y(d.visits) )
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", d => color(d['scrollreach_label']))
```